# How do I play just one song in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

In Windows Media Player, when I right click one song and then click play, it plays just one song (it doesn't advance to the next track when song finishes), and when I double click a song, it plays the next songs in list when the first song has finished. How do I play just one song in Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before play, Locate the Music in Rhythmbox, and then click add to Playlist.

So just the playlist will be executed, ie, as one only has music, only they will be executed.

Comment: I have been googling a little and it seems most music players work that way